# Ошибка 404 при создании новой страницы

Tags: php, yii2

при создании папки user и в ней новых страниц, на сайте они не отображаются, вместо отображения выдаёт ошибку 404. А с папки site эти страницы отображаются без ошибки. В чём может быть проблема?

Вот два файла созданные в папке views/user
[image: Виды]

main.php

```
['label' => 'Войти', 'url' => ['/user/login'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
['label' => 'Регистрация', 'url' => ['/user/reg'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]]
```

SignupController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\RegForm;

class SignupController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionReg()
    {
        $model = new RegForm();

        return $this->render(
            'reg',
            [
                'model' => $model    
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

SigninController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\LoginForm;

class SigninController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model = new LoginForm();

        return $this->render(
            'login',
            [
                'model' => $model    
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать UserController и в нём написать экшены для тех вьюх которые Вы создали. Без контроллера и экшенов ваши вьюхи это просто файлы. И если они не рендерятся ни в одном месте сайта, то Вы их и не откроете.

Самый простой пример:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;    
class UserController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
  public function actionLogin()
  {
    return $this->render('login');
  }
}
```

P.S. Исходя из кода Ваших контроллеров, вьюхи должны лежать в папках `views/signup/reg.php` и `views/signin/login.php` соответственно. То есть имя папки внутри `views` соответствует началу имени контроллера.

Comment: обновил ответ..

Comment: Да точно. Спасибо большое. Очень выручили)